# Бесконечно вложенный сам в себя список

Tags: python, алгоритм

Имеется два числа, допустим массив в три ячейки и 1, 2 по его бокам, а в центре должен быть сам список. По сути, массив, который уходит в бесконечность. Пример: [1, [1, [1... 2], 2], 2]. Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: при чём здесь фрактал? (потому что некоторые фракталы самоподобные?) Вы хотите список, который сам на себя ссылается? Вы рекурсивную структуру хотите создать? [Self-referencing lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15849399/4279)

Answer (score 4):

```
lst = [1,2]
lst.insert(1, lst)
print(lst) # [1, [...], 2]
print(lst[1][1][1][2]) # 2
```

Comment: А как такое можно реализовать, если необходимо больше одной фрактальной ячейки в массиве?

Comment: `a = []; a.extend((a, a))` -> `[[...], [...]]`.

Answer (score -1):

```
fractal = [0, 2]
fractal.insert(1, fractal)
fractal.insert(1, fractal)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Достаточно одной вставки (если вы отвечаете на исходный ответ, а не комментарий под другим ответом).